# Matlab: index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I have written code for histogram equalization of colored image. The code works fine for gray-scale image but it throws error for colored image. I am converting rgb image to hsv and then performing histogram equalization. Any idea about this?

Code:

```
%  GIm=imread('tire.tif'); this is grayscale image, which works fine
I=imread('D:\came.jpg');
GIm=rgb2hsv(I);% converting color image to hsv
numofpixels=size(GIm,1)*size(GIm,2);
figure,imshow(GIm);
title('Original Image');
HIm=uint8(zeros(size(GIm,1),size(GIm,2)));
freq=zeros(256,1);
probf=zeros(256,1);
probc=zeros(256,1);
cum=zeros(256,1);
output=zeros(256,1);
%freq counts the occurrence of each pixel value.
%The probability of each occurrence is calculated by probf.
for i=1:size(GIm,1)
    for j=1:size(GIm,2)
        value=GIm(i,j);
        freq(value+1)=freq(value+1)+1; % giving error here 
        probf(value+1)=freq(value+1)/numofpixels;
    end

end

sum=0;
no_bins=255;
%The cumulative distribution probability is calculated. 
for i=1:size(probf)
   sum=sum+freq(i);
   cum(i)=sum;
   probc(i)=cum(i)/numofpixels;
   output(i)=round(probc(i)*no_bins);
end

for i=1:size(GIm,1)
    for j=1:size(GIm,2)
            HIm(i,j)=output(GIm(i,j)+1);
    end
end

figure,imshow(HIm);
title('Histogram equalization');
subplot(2,2,2); 
plot(GIm);
%bar(GIm);
title('Before Histogram equalization');
subplot(2,2,4);
plot(HIm)
%bar(HIm);
title('After Histogram equalization');
```

Error:

```
Attempted to access freq(1.61378); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in histogramequ (line 18)
        freq(value+1)=freq(value+1)+1;
```

Comment: James - look closer at the HSV image, `GIm`.  In the Command Window type `class(GIm)` and `max(GIm(:))`.  What you will probably notice is that the HSV data type (class) is **double** and that the maximum value is 1.  And so all pixel values are in the interval [0,1] and the error message makes sense.  Also check the dimensions on the RGB and HSV images.  There may be three dimensions unlike the two dimensions for the grayscale images.  Your code may have to be updated to handle this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would create a histogram - perhaps one for each of the hue, saturation and value components (of the HSV image) splitting the [0,1] interval into a fixed number of bins.  For example, [0,0.1), [0.1, 0.2), ...,[0.8,0.9), [0.9,1] could be the ten bins that you would try to "fill".  Though you probably want considerably more of them (this is just an example).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code is after rgb2hsv(), the format of each pixel is double in [0,1], rather than uint8. So you need to convert back to [0,255] so it can be used as a subscript.

The following code will work properly.

```
for i=1:size(GIm,1)
    for j=1:size(GIm,2)
        value=floor(GIm(i,j) * 255);  % now value is in [0,255]
        freq(value+1)=freq(value+1)+1;
        probf(value+1)=freq(value+1)/numofpixels;
    end
end
```